# »Würden Sie den mir schicken« oder »Würden Sie mir den schicken«?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Was ist richtig?

> Würden Sie den mir schicken?

oder

> Würden Sie mir den schicken?

*Den* bezieht sich auf den Brief.

Comment: Ein klein wenig mehr Kontext zur tatsächlichen Situation wäre hilfreich. Rein grammatikalisch sind bede Varianten korrekt.

Answer (score 2):

> Was ist richtig?

Beides ist richtig, die Bedeutung kann aber je nach Betonung ein wenig anders sein.

Der Satz

> > Würden **Sie** den mir schicken?

beispielsweise fragt ob die angesprochene Person der/die Absender/in des Briefes des Briefes sein wird. Ansonsten wäre die Satzstellung eher unüblich.
Auch dann, wäre eher

> Würden **Sie** mir den schicken?

die wahrscheinlich gängigere Form, aber grammatikalisch richtig ist trotzdem Beides.

---

Die 2. Variante

> > Würden Sie mir **den** *(bitte)* schicken?

könnte z.B. eher als Bitte an die Person verstanden werden, den Brief weiterzuleiten.

Comment: Die erste Variante klingt für mich insbesondere als "Würden Sie den **mir** schicken?" naheliegend, also als Frage nach dem Empfänger.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja. Auf die Idee bin ich nicht gekommen. Es ist aber nach wie vor eine Frage der Betonung in gesprochener Sprache.

Answer (score -4):

### Kurze Antwort:

Nur diese Version ist richtig:

> Würden Sie mir den schicken?

---

### Lange Antwort:

It's complicated.

### Regel 1

(gilt immer)

Zum richtigen Satzbau findet man, wenn man mit der Stellung SOV (Subjekt - Objekt - Verb) beginnt, und dann zwei Umbauten macht:

SOV, das ist auch die Reihenfolge in einem Nebensatz:

> ich Äpfel mag
>   Ich esse Äpfel, weil **ich Äpfel mag**.

Dann das Verb an Position 1 schieben (das ergibt die Reihenfolge eines geschlossenen Fragesatzes):

> mag ich Äpfel
>   **Mag ich Äpfel?**

Und dann eines der Satzglieder, die nicht zum Verb, gehören nach vorne bringen. Dafür gibt es mehrere Möglichkeiten:

> 1. Ich mag Äpfel.
> 2. Äpfel mag ich.

**Verfeinerung:**
Wenn in solchen Regel von einem *Verb* die Rede ist, dann ist eigentlich das *Prädikat* ohne Prädikatsergänzungen gemeint, also das Hauptverb zusammen mit einem eventuell vorhandenen Hilfsverb, und einem ebenfalls noch möglichen Infinitiv. In diesem Fall stehen zu Beginn (in der Nebensatz-Version) alle genannten Bestandteile am Ende des Satzes, in dieser Reihenfolge:

- Infinitiv (falls vorhanden)
- Hauptverb
- Hilfsverb (falls vorhanden)

> *(Ich mag Erich, weil)* **Erich den Hund führt.**
>   *(Ich mag Erich, weil)* **Erich den Hund spazieren führt.**
>   *(Ich mag Erich, weil)* **Erich den Hund geführt hat.**
>   *(Ich mag Erich, weil)* **Erich den Hund spazieren geführt hat.**

Dann wandert nur das letze Wort nach vorne, und man erhält die Wortfolge einer geschlossenen Frage:

> Führt Erich den Hund?
>   Führt Erich den Hund spazieren?
>   Hat Erich den Hund geführt?
>   Hat Erich den Hund spazieren geführt?

Es bleiben also Teile des Prädikats hinten stehen, falls es aus mehr als nur einem Wort besteht. Diese Teile müssen auch beim zweiten Schritt hinten stehen bleiben:

> Erich führt den Hund.
>   Den Hund führt Erich.
>
> Erich führt den Hund spazieren.
>   Den Hund führt Erich spazieren.
>
> Erich hat den Hund geführt.
>   Den Hund hat Erich geführt.
>
> Erich hat den Hund spazieren geführt.
>   Den Hund hat Erich spazieren geführt.

---

### Regel 2

(wenn es sowohl ein Dativ- als auch ein Akkusativobjekt gibt)

Aus der Regel 1 folgt, dass das Subjekt in einem Aussagesatz entweder an Stelle 1 stehen muss, oder direkt hinter der finiten Form des Verbs. Sie lässt aber offen, in welcher Reihenfolge die Satzteile anzuordnen sind, die weder Verb (Prädikat) noch Subjekt sind. Das ist nämlich etwas kompliziert. (Ich stelle in allen folgenden Beispielen das Subjekt an Position 1.)

**a) beide Objekte sind Nomen oder Nominalgruppen**

Wenn das Akkusativobjekt einen unbestimmten Artikel hat, steht der Dativ immer vor dem Akkusativ:

> Der König gibt seinem Heer einen Befehl.
>   <del>*Der König gibt einen Befehl seinem Heer.*</del>

Bei einem bestimmten Artikel ist diese Reihenfolge zwar die bevorzugte, aber ein Umstellen ist möglich, um eine besondere Betonung zu erreichen:

> Der König gibt seinem Heer den Befehl. (richtig)
>   Der König gibt den Befehl seinem Heer. (möglich, um etwas zu betonen)

Das geht aber nur mit bestimmten Artikeln, nicht mit anderen Determinierern:

> Peter überreicht seiner Freundin rote Rosen.
>   <del>*Peter überreicht rote Rosen seiner Freundin.*</del>

aber:

> Peter überreicht die Rosen seiner Freundin. (der bestimmte Artikel erlaubt das Vorziehen des Akkusativobjekts)

**b) eines der beiden Objekte ist ein Personalpronomen, das andere nicht**

In diesem Fall steht das Personalpronomen immer vor dem anderen Satzteil, unabhängig vom grammatischen Fall:

Personalpronomen im Dativ:

> Der König gibt ihm einen Befehl.
>   <del>*Der König gibt einen Befehl ihm.*</del>

Personalpronomen im Akkusativ:

> Der König gibt ihn dem Heer.
>   <del>*Der König gibt dem Heer ihn.*</del>

Diese Regel gilt auch, wenn zwei Pronomen aufeinandertreffen, von denen aber nur eines ein Personalpronomen ist:

Personalpronomen im Dativ:

> Der König gibt ihm keinen.
>   <del>*Der König gibt keinen ihm.*</del>

Personalpronomen im Akkusativ:

> Der König gibt ihn jemandem.
>   <del>*Der König gibt jemandem ihn.*</del>

**c) beide Objekte sind Personalpronomen**

Aus den vorherigen Regeln könnte man die Faustregel *"Dativ vor Akkusativ; mit Ausnahmen"* ableiten, aber wenn beide Objekte Personalpronomen sind, ist es genau umgekehrt, also Akkusativ vor Dativ:

> Der König gibt ihn ihm.
>   <del>*Der König gibt ihm ihn.*</del>

---

### Wahlfreiheit

Die oft behauptete Wahlfreiheit (»Man darf Dativ und Akkusativ beliebig anordnen«) existiert also nur dann, wenn beide Objekte Nomen oder Nominalgruppen sind, und auch dann gibt es unter den beiden Möglichkeiten einen klaren Favoriten.

---

### erlaubte Varianten des Beispielsatzes

Bei dem Satz handelt es sich um eine geschlossene Frage, daher steht das finite Verb (hier: das Hilfsverb) an Position 1, und das Subjekt an Position 2 (folgt aus Regel 1). Der infinite Teil des Verbs muss am Ende stehen (folgt auch aus Regel 1), und Regel 2c verlangt, dass das Personalpronomen vor dem Relativpronomen steht.

Daher ist als Frage nur diese Form erlaubt:

> Würden Sie mir den schicken?

Comment: Was motiviert die Hinuntervotierungen?

Comment: Das würde mich auch interessieren. Bitte um Feedback, damit ich es in Zukunft besser machen kann.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: weil Du's bist und weil Du herzlich drum bittest: schon der erste und dann der letzte Absatz sind m.E. nicht ganz korrekt. Man kann durchaus sagen: *Würden Sie den **mir** schicken (und nicht dem Chef)?* - beim Rest deines Beitrags habe ich Mühe, den Bezug zur Frage zu finden.